# Converting data from an array into a data validation list using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, validation

I have an unidimensional array that can have more the 50 elements and I'd like to know a way to add it into an excel cell.
I'm using PHPExcel, and I know I must use `PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST` to do it, but I didn't find a way to pass the elements of my array to an excel cell.
In fact, what I want is to count how many elements I have in this array and set the same dropdown (data validation list) as many times as the amount of elements, in the cells of the `A` column.

Can someone give me any idea?

**EDIT - Explaining a little more the problem:** I have a list of block names, and i'm trying to create a template file that the user can download to update data of new blocks. If he add a different block name, it will create a new block, instead of updating, this is why I want to use a data validation list in each cell of the 'A' column inside a sheet. This way the user can select block names that already exists (he won't make confusion writing its names). Also, he doesn't need to have all the blocks in the cells, because he can update data of 2 blocks in a list with more than 50 blocks. (if he has all the blocks filling the cells, when he upload the template, he will also upload the data of the blocks that he left empty... I think now it's easier to understand my problem.

Comment: Do you really want a data validation list, or do you simply want to populate each cell in a column from an entry in your array? I'm confused by the question

Comment: I really want a data validation list... I want to generate this xls file and let the user choose some information found in the data validation list, to help him to not insert different names of the ones found in my db. Also, I don't want to obligate him to insert information about all the data I want to let him choose by using the data validation form (the dropdown). Did it get better to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved it. I found out the problem:

```
    $blocksList = implode (", ", $blockNames);
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("lalala SAS")
                ->setTitle("Bulk Upload Template");
    //Data Validation list
    $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list');
    $objValidation->setFormula1('"'.$blocksList.'"');
```

The problem is that my $blocksKist is too big and excel formula support only 255 characters. This way, I'll add my `$blocksList` into another sheet and read it from that.

Comment: Hi, can we read the set of options from the drop-down list using phpexcel? something like getFormula1() is there anything like this?

Comment: the dropdown list u refer is a data validation list in excel, right? If so, the options in this list should be available in some sheet (maybe in a hidden sheet?), so an idea I'm thinking now is to read the range that groups these options in the sheet it is stored.